# Using a book cover in a book review on Blog Overflow

Tags: support, blog

On the Seasoned Advice community blog, we're planning on running a book review this Wednesday. (Its all ready and scheduled in Wordpress). This review is quite positive (though really, that shouldn't matter, I hope).

In particular, we're using a cover image of the book (grabbed from Amazon) to illustrate the review. The image is linked to the Amazon product page, through the rads.so.

I just want to make sure that we're not going to get anyone in trouble doing this. The cover image is copyrighted, after all, but it seems like this use would be fair use under US law—but I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: I think that using a book cover in a review is fair use too, and a publisher won't complain about a positive review anyway. What I am worried about is our CC content: once we put something on the blog, it seems to automatically become CC, and I don't think that fair use allows us to distribute other people's copyrighted images under CC.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate that the image has a copyright that's different from CC?

Comment: @norabora: We could certainly add an editors note at the bottom about the copyright status of the cover image

Comment: @rumtscho: isn't that exactly what Wikipedia does?